# MySQL Prepared Statement Binds do not Match Fields

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a function to aid me in making prepared calls to the database, which I've never had a problem with until now, which is the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in /var/www/file.php

This is my function

```
function GetPrepared($SQL, $Types = null, $Params = null) {
    global $dbs;
    # create a prepared statement
    $Statement = $dbs->prepare($SQL);

    # bind parameters for markers
    # but this is not dynamic enough...
    //$stmt->bind_param("s", $parameter);

    if (!empty($Statement)) {
        if ($Types && $Params) {
            $bind_names[] = $Types;
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($Params); $i++) {
                $bind_name = 'bind' . $i;
                $$bind_name = $Params[$i];
                $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name;
            }
            $return = call_user_func_array(array($Statement, 'bind_param'), $bind_names);
        }

        # execute query 
        $Statement->execute();

        # these lines of code below return one dimentional array, similar to mysqli::fetch_assoc()
        $meta = $Statement->result_metadata();


        if (!empty($meta)) {
            while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
                $var = $field->name;
                $$var = null;
                $parameters[$field->name] = &$$var;
            }

            call_user_func_array(array($Statement, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

            while ($Statement->fetch()) {
                return $parameters;
                //print_r($parameters);      
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
    # close statement
    $Statement->close();
}
```

And here's the query that I'm attempting to run, but getting that error above

```
$OptionData = GetPrepared("select * from `options` join `fields` on `fields`.`FieldID`=`options`.`FieldID` where `CompanyID`=? and (replace(`options`.`Name`, ' ', '') =? or `Slug`=?);", 'sss', array($_CompanyID, $_GET['id'], $_GET['id']));
```

The values of `$_GET['id']` is text and `$_CompanyID` is a guid, both of which are set, because I can echo out both of their contents before the call is made. Also, if I go ahead and take this query into Workbench and replace the question marks with their values, the query works just fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Since the code worked before and you didn't made any changes, the problem must come from the database results. Most likely the `options` and `fields` tables now have common fields (e.g. `id` or `name`), which cause your `$parameters` array to have in the end less items than there are columns, as the `$parameters[$field->name] = &$$var;` assignment can't handle multiple fields with the same name.

I'd recommend that you use the approach suggested [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#102179), and create a "regular" php array instead of an associative one:

```
while($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
    $variables[] = &$data[$field->name]; // pass by reference
}
```

Comment: What I meant by the function has been working was that it was working on all the queries, and that this was the first query that it could not work on

Comment: Check then if those two tables don't have common fields

Comment: They do have `Name` in common, but with your code I'm still getting that error

Comment: And I don't think that's the error, since the function appears to already be doing what you've suggested. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the error happens before the `fetch_field` stage. Especially because the error links me to this line `$return = call_user_func_array(array($Statement, 'bind_param'), $bind_names);`

Comment: The warning from your question is for `bind_result()`, not `bind_param()`, do  you get a warning on that line too? In this case the `$Statement->execute();` cal should fail. Also, why do you have `$Statement->close();` after return?

Comment: Whoops, good point about the last line. But I think I've found a better solution. Instead of making that MySQL statement work (which it shouldn't; that would be wrong), I fixed the statement by not having it return two variables with the same name

Comment: That would work too. I'd recommend in this case adding a comment to the `GetPrepared()` documentation in case you forget about this behaviour, or you make the function available to other developers too.